Saving an Apache Echart causes tainted canvas error
Saving the chart via the toolbox.feature.saveAsImage causes an error that says Tainted Canvas may not be exported. However, saving the image manually via right-clicking on the chart itself works just fine. I was wondering if there are any work-around on this? For deeper context, I've added images to the axis labels of the chart which may have caused it to become "tainted"
I've already tried using html2canvas together with the on render event handler of apache echart and it still doesn't work. I've tried forwarding my port publicly and it also doesn't work

Load the images from your own server. See also CORS enabled image. Notice, that the response headers of the image must be set correctly, you can't set the headers on a third-party server.
